# Why Socks5 can go through firewall?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, firewall, socks

I have read socks5's RFC, but I still don't understand why TCP and UDP packets can be passed through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to simply bypass a (properly configured) firewall by using the SOCKS protocol and this is also not the intention of the protocol.

In the context of firewalls a SOCKS server is a proxy server which is explicitly installed at the firewall in order to provide internal clients with restricted access to the outside. This usually means that most outgoing traffic except SOCKS is blocked by the firewall and that the SOCKS server is configured to only allow authenticated connections (based on IP, user or similar) and maybe even restrict where specific users can connect to. Insofar it is similar to a HTTP proxy.

Comment: Taking shadowsocks as an example, socks installed proxies on both the local and the server. As far as I know, it was not installed on the firewall. Why are TCP and UDP packets not detected by the firewall after these two socks proxies, what do socks do to them?

Comment: @XiangtingLiu: Shadowsocks is a local SOCKS proxy. It does not use SOCKS to bypass the firewall at all. SOCKS is only used between the local client and the local shadowsocks instance.